# Remove action within a class in a parent theme's includes folder from the child theme

Tags: hooks, actions, child-theme

There's a class in parent's theme *includes* folder which adds action i want to remove in the child theme functions.php or in the plugin

```
class A {
   public function __construct() {
      ...
      add_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', array( $this, 'before_customer_login_form' ) );
      ...
   }


    public function before_customer_login_form() {
        echo ( 'yes' !== get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) ) ? '<div id="customer_login" class="woocommerce-content-box full-width">' : '';
    }
}
```

*functions.php* code inspired by solution from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/280767/remove-action-within-a-class-in-a-parent-theme-from-the-child-theme)

```
function remove_woo_forms_hooks() {
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', array('A','before_customer_login_form'));
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_woo_forms_hooks',0);
```

Though action removal doesn't work. *before_customer_login_form* action is still fired.

Suspect that the code

`remove_action('woocommerce_before_customer_login_form',array('A','before_customer_login_form'));`

is not correct.

How to remove the action correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove action hook done in a plugin from functions.php in my theme?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/258764/how-to-remove-action-hook-done-in-a-plugin-from-functions-php-in-my-theme)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot to *Nathan Johnson*:

The solution was to use instance of the class the action was defined in.
The class was globalized in the theme after instantiation.
So the adding the below code to functions.php of a Child Theme worked:

```
function remove_woo_forms_hooks() {
    global $woo_a;
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_customer_login_form', array($woo_a,'before_customer_login_form'));
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_woo_forms_hooks',0);
```